How to fetch data with the given order from the database ? (django)
I have a model in which there are different fields of data, and a field of "section-order" is given. now i want to fetch that data into the bootstrap accordians with respect to the "section-order". for example the section-order = 1 should come in first accordion and likewise
**MODELS **
class casestudy_list(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class CaseStudyContent(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    case_study = models.ForeignKey(casestudy_list, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section_order = models.IntegerField()
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    content_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='casestudy/images', default="")



   def __str__(self):
       return self.section_title

VIEWS
def home(request):
    casestudy_obj = casestudy_list.objects.all().values()
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    context = {
    'casestudy_obj' : casestudy_obj, #making the object for accessing purposes
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def casestudy(request, id):
    casestudy_obj = casestudy_list.objects.get(id=id)
    template = loader.get_template('casestudy.html')
    context = {
    'casestudy_obj' : casestudy_obj, #making the object for accessing purposes
   
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

on the home page, once the user clicks on any link it reidrects to the casestudy page.

Please paste your code as text in your question, not as images. This will help us to identify your problem without retyping it.

Use the render function to make the code a bit more concise. Sort your queryset according to section_order with the order_by() method.
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def casestudy(request, id):
    # results in 404 error when no object is found with given id
    casestudy_obj = get_object_or_404(casestudy_list, id=id)
    casestudy_content = CaseStudyContent.objects.filter(case_study=casestudy_obj).order_by('section_order')
    context = {
        'casestudy_obj': casestudy_obj,
        'casestudy_content': casestudy_content,
    }
    return render(request, 'casestudy.html', context)

Then, with those two variables passed to the casestudy.html template you can insert it via curly braces.
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  {% for content in casestudy_content %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading{{ content.id }}">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{ content.id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{ content.id }}">
                    {{ content.section_title }}
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse{{ content.id }}" class="collapse {% if forloop.first %}show{% endif %}" aria-labelledby="heading{{ content.id }}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>{{ content.content_text }}</p>
                {% if content.content_img %}
                <img src="{{ content.content_img.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="{{ content.section_title }}">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

You did not show your template. I hope above example for an accordion helps.
